# assembly / __asm inlining

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, inline-assembly

I am learning assembly and making some inlining in my Digital Mars C++ compiler. I searched some things to make a program better and had these parameters to tune the programs:

```
use better C++ compiler//thinking of GCC or intel compiler

use assembly only in critical part of program 

find better algorithm

Cache miss, cache contention.

Loop-carried dependency chain.

Instruction fetching time.

Instruction decoding time.

Instruction retirement.

Register read stalls.

Execution port throughput.

Execution unit throughput.

Suboptimal reordering and scheduling of micro-ops.

Branch misprediction.

Floating point exception.
```

I understood all except "register read stalls".

Question: Can anybody tell me how is this happening in CPU and the "superscalar" form of the "out of order execution"? 
Normal "out of order" seemed logical but i couldnt find a logical explanation of "superscalar" form.

Question 2: Can someone alse give some good instruction list of SSE SSE2 and newer CPU's prefarably with micro-ops table, port throughputs, units and some calculation table for the latencies to find the real bottle-neck of a piece of code?

I would be happy with a small example like this:

```
//loop carried dependency chain breaking:
__asm
{
loop_begin:
....
.... 
sub edx,05h //rather than taking i*5 in each iteration, we sub 5 each iteration
sub ecx,01h //i-- counter
...
...
jnz loop_begin//edit: sub ecx must have been after the sub edx for jnz
}
//while sub edx makes us get rid of a multiplication also makes that independent of ecx, making independent
```

Thank you.

Computer: Pentium-M 2GHz , Windows XP-32 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at Agner Fogs optimization manuals: [Optimizing software in C++: An optimization guide for Windows, Linux and Mac platforms](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) or [Optimizing subroutines in assembly language: An optimization guide for x86 platforms](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf).

But to really be able to outsmart a modern compiler, you need some good background knowledge of the arch you want to optimize for: [The microarchitecture of Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs: An optimization guide for assembly programmers and compiler makers](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf)

Comment: i already read some of Agners' they are good but for some small parts i needed other sources. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: [Intel Architecture Developers Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/)
Really detailed, there are all SSE instructions as well, with opcodes, instruction latency and throughput, and all gory details you might need :)

Answer (score 1):

The "superscalar" stalls is an added problem for scheduling instructions. A modern processor can not only execute instructions out of order, it can also do 3-4 simple instructions at a time, using parallel execution units.

But to actually do that, the instructions must be sufficiently independent of each other. If, for example, one instruction uses the result of a previous instruction, it must wait for that result to be available.

In practice, this makes creating an optimal assembly program by hand *extremely* difficult. You really have to be like a computer (compiler) to calculate the optimal order of the instructions. And if you change one instruction, you have to do it all over again....

Answer (score 1):

For question #1 I would highly recommend [Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012383872X). It does a very good job of explaining the concepts in context, so you can see the big picture. The examples are also very useful for a person who is interested in optimizing code, because they always focus on *prioritizing* and improving the bottleneck.